# XML deserialization of derived classes C#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have next code:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Container")]
public class Container {
    [XmlArray("Items", IsNullable = false)]
    [XmlArrayItem("Item")]
    public List<BaseItem> Items { get; set; } = new List<BaseItem>();
}


public class BaseItem {
    [XmlAttribute("SomeField")]
    public string SomeField {get;set;}
}


public class DerivedItem : BaseItem {
    [XmlAttribute("OtherField")]
    public string OtherField {get;set;}
}
```

How can I deserialize:

```
<Container>
   <Items>
        <Item SomeField="Value"/>
        <Item SomeField="Value" OtherField="OtherValue"/>
   </Items>
</Container>
```

so, Items field in Container object can contain BaseItem and DerivedItem objects from XML above?

Comment: `XmlSerializer` determines the type from the element name.  Would it be acceptable to have `<DerivedItem SomeField="Value" OtherField="OtherValue"/>` instead?

Comment: Actually this is not valid XML - so all answers are crap. You MUST separate inheritance by element name per XML standards. You then define multiple XmlArrayItem entries with name and type of the subclass. THIS is XML - what you ask here has no xml derived classses as per XML Specification.

Comment: Alternatively, would you be willing to have `<Item xsi:type="DerivedItem" SomeField="Value" OtherField="OtherValue"/>` ?  You can do this by adding [`[XmlInclude(typeof(DerivedItem))]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  See also [Xsi:type Attribute Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca1ks327%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: dbc, already tried that. and that's what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't because when deserializing the XmlSerializer does not determine when to use BaseItem or DerivedItem. So imho you should not use inheritance here.

Now what you possibly needed is to know if OtherField is specified or not.

Fortunately this is something the XmlSerializer CAN do. For this you need to add to your class representing the item a bool property OtherFieldSpecified which indicates if OtherField is well... specified.

You should use

```
// Define other methods and classes here
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Container")]
public class Container {
    [XmlArray("Items", IsNullable = false)]
    [XmlArrayItem("Item")]
    public List<DerivedItem> Items { get; set; }

}

public class DerivedItem
{
    [XmlAttribute("SomeField")]
    public string SomeField {get;set;}

    [XmlAttribute("OtherField")]
    public string OtherField {get;set;}

    public bool OtherFieldSpecified {get;set;}
}
```

So a little adjust working linqPad scribble gave me this code:

```
void Main()
{

var xml = @"
<Container>
<Items>
        <Item SomeField=""Value""/>
        <Item SomeField=""Value"" OtherField=""OtherValue""/>
</Items>
</Container>
";

var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml));

    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Container));

    var container = (Container) ser.Deserialize(stream);

    container.Dump();
}
```

Comment: Well, he CAN - if he adheres to XML standard, which his samlple data does not. The sample data does not contain any derived elements as per XML specification. As he asks about a XML solution - your solution is not working.

Comment: He wants to deserialize the given XML... I gave him a working, valid version for deserializing that.

Comment: No, that is not what he says. You imly that he has no control. IF he has - then this is not a derived class solution. See, what happens if you look at the XML schema? Ups, not working with derived classes.

Comment: I'm not implying he is not in control. His XML is valid. He never bothered to show use the schema to validate against. I just showed a way to change the code so the xml he posted is read using the XmlSerializer i'm assuming he is using.

Comment: YOu are awaer of site rules? "SHow minimal code to demonstrate a problem". You draw conclusions from a simplistic sample or accuse him to be not smart enough to follow the site rules.

Comment: Well, your right, i did draw some conclusions as i'm aware of the site rules regarding that. Thanks for your critisism.

Answer (score 0):

Can we start with you not posting valid XML?

Elements are unique. Inheritance (derived types) MUST change the element name. THis is XML standard because the element name is how the XML Schema determines what elements exist.

YOu do that then you can add multiple XmlArrayItem entries - there is a second overload that takes the type of the included item.

Comment: Actually, the attribute `xsi:type="DerivedItem"` can also be used to specify the type.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type and [Xsi:type Attribute Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca1ks327%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  And in any event the raw XML is perfectly valid, it just that the desired schema mapping is not supported by the serializer.